# ¿Cómo agregar una variable a una URL?

Tags: variables, url, enlace

Estoy intentando hacer una URL con variable.

El objetivo es hacer que una persona escriba un número en un formulario `[234893]` y al tocar el botón sea dirigido a `"http://ejemplo.com/"` + `"234893"` y a esto sumarle el signo `"#"` al finalizar para que el enlace termine siendo `"http://ejemplo.com/234893#"`.

De momento, he conseguido las 2 primeras cosas. Me hace falta que añada el `"#"` al final del enlace.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function setNombre() {
        var miUrl = "http://ejemplo.com/" + document.getElementById("txtNombre").value;
        window.open(miUrl);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Número de Tarjeta: <input id="txtNombre" type="text" name="fname" /><br />

    <button id="btnEnv" type="button" onclick="setNombre()">Enviar</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Concatena tu variable como ya lo hiciste `var miUrl = "http://ejemplo.com/" + document.getElementById('txtNombre').value + "#";`

Comment: mmm.. no sé si hice algo mal, pero no me ha funcionado.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function setNombre() {
    var miUrl = "http://www.megatarjeta.com.co/Movtarjeta/web?TAR=" + document.getElementById('txtNombre').value + "#";
    window.open(miUrl);
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  Número de Tarjeta: <input id="txtNombre" type="text" name="fname"><br>
  
  <button id="btnSaldo" type="button" onclick="setNombre()">Consultar Saldo</button>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: Olvídalo, si funciona correctamente en PC. Pero en la App de Android no funciona correctamente. el "window.open(miUrl);" no funciona en Android? Ayúda por favor xd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function setNombre() {
                var miUrl= "https://ejemplo.com/" + document.getElementById('valor').value + "#";
                document.write("abre url: "  + miUrl);
                window.open(miUrl);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Introduzca número: <input id="valor" type="text">            
        <button id="btnConcatena" type="button" onclick="setNombre()">Enviar</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

En este caso si introduces "234893" se abrirá la url:

https://ejemplo.com/234893#